# High school indefinite integration question: $\int 1/(x^2+6x+5)dx $ but must complete the square then use a trigonometric substitution.

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

$$
\int \frac{1}{x^2+6x+5} \, dx
$$
I thought I did the steps correctly but I may have the wrong substitution.

So first I completed the square:
$$
\int\frac{1}{(x+3)^2-4} \, dx
$$
Then I used the substitution of $ x= 2\sin \theta -3$
and then found $ dx= 2 \cos \theta \, d\theta $

I then subbed in these values to create $$\int \frac{2\cos\theta}{4( \sin^2 \theta -1)} \, d\theta$$

This leads to
$$
-\frac{1}{2}\int \sec \theta \, d \theta
$$
And the answer I got is
$$
-\frac{1}{2} \ln\lvert\sec x + \tan x\rvert +c 
$$
However, this is not the correct answer according to an online integration calculator. Can anyone help me figure out where I went wrong (probably the substitution)?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange, Nateylion. Don't worry about the formatting—you did a good job for someone new to this site. Use ``\sec`` and ``\tan`` for trigonometric functions and ``\ln`` for the natural logarithm. Also, use ``\frac{a}{b}`` for the fraction $\frac{a}{b}$.

Comment: That should be $-\frac12|\sec\theta+\tan\theta|+c$, not $-\frac12|\sec x+\tan x|+c$. And now you have to back-substitute $\theta=\sin^{-1}((x+3)/2)$. (But Sidvhid Hsinyjad's method is easier!)

Comment: @TonyK Yep I definitely forgot to back substitute thanks.

Comment: @LalitTolani What substitution do you recommend? I don't see how a trigonometric substitution can cover all the values. But then again I'm quite new to integration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up to the point where you list the answer as $\frac{-1}{2}\int \sec(\theta)d\theta$ is correct. However, this integral is $\frac{-1}{2}\ln(\sec(\theta)+\tan(\theta)),$ not $\frac{-1}{2}\ln(\sec(x)+\tan(x))$. You must integrate with respect to $\theta$ and then change it back to $x$. When $\sin(\theta) = \frac{x+3}{2}$,
$$\frac{-1}{2} \ln(\sec\theta+\tan\theta)= \frac{-1}{2}\ln\left(\frac{2}{\sqrt{4-(x+3)^2}}+\frac{(x+3)}{\sqrt{4-(x+3)^2}}\right)$$
Where I've calculated $\sec\theta$ and $\tan\theta$ using your substitution. Algebra should take you to the answer. I'd collect into one fraction, split into two logarithms, and then take the square roots out as coefficients.

Sidvhid correctly points out that partial fractions is much, much easier.

Comment: Oops I typed x instead of \theta.  Thanks anyway I'm definitely going to use this solution. I simply forgot to back substitute but I guess I'll get used to it after doing enough integration.